# LinkOpen::linke: Specified file is not a MathLink executable. in AceGen

Tags: finite-element-method, mathlink-or-wstp, acegen

I tried to run AceGen/AceFEM on my Mac(10.15.5).
I installed Mathematica (12.1.0.0) successfully and also the latest version of the AcePackage (7.113). The installation of the AcePackage is successful, saying the C compiler is found.
Now I can build an element (from the MainLibrary) for example, but running a simulation is not possible. Both packages can be loaded, but executing the `SMTInputData[];` command gives the following error.

```
LinkOpen: Specified file is not a MathLink executable..

External numerical module is closed. Please restart Mathematica and try again. If the error repeats rebuild and recompile all user elements in debug mode.
```

The latest version of Xcode is installed as well.

What can I do?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supporting the new Mac OS has become a problem. Apple has dropped support for OpenMP parallelization. One of those strange decisions apple does occasionally... I hope that 7.114 version will work also on all Macs.

Answer (score 0):

Updated 7.114 version has been tasted on various MAcs. So far OK.